# backbone rails save not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript

I am new to Backbone and I'm having problem saving a model to database. When clicking, the field 'profile' should be updated to '100', but it is not working:

$ ->

```
class User extends Backbone.Model
    url: -> '/users/' + this.get("id")  '.json'

class Users extends Backbone.Collection
    model: User

class UserView extends Backbone.View
    tagName: "li"
    events:
        "click" : "changeProfile"

    render: -> $(@el).html( @model.get "name" )
    changeProfile: -> 
        $('li').removeClass('selected')
        $(@el).addClass('selected')
        @model.set( 'profile' : '100' ).save()

users = new Users
users.url = "/users.json"
users.fetch(
    success: ->
        _.each users.models, (model) ->
            view = new UserView( model: model )
            $('ul').append view.render()
)
```

The 'users' controller / 'user' model were scaffolded (and the controller renders in json). I am using latest versions of both Backbone and Rails. Can somebody help?

(Javascript Console in Chrome register the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `url` for `User` is missing a `+`:

```
class User extends Backbone.Model
    url: -> '/users/' + this.get("id")  '.json'
    #---------------------------------^^
```

The last part of that is being interpreted like this:

```
this.get("id")('.json')
```

and since `get('id')` is returning a number, you get a "number is not a function" error. Add the missing `+` to get string concatenation or use CoffeeScript's interpolation:

```
url: -> '/users/' + this.get('id') + '.json'
```

or

```
url: -> "/users/#{this.get('id')}.json"
```